# Content appears behind opaque navigation bar when action bar is transparent

Tags: android, material-design

I'm trying to implement a theme which has a completely transparent action and status bar with an opaque navigation bar. Basically something which looks similar to an example given on [Google's Material Design website](http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/imagery.html#imagery-ui-integration).

[image]

Here's some XML code I've written to create a theme which comes pretty close -

```
 <style name="MyTheme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>

    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>

    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

However, as you can see in this image, content appears behind the navigation bar at the bottom. This would be fine in a design where the user is expected to scroll vertically, however, I don't want to do that! I want all the content to fit without any scrolling whatsoever.

I figured I'd be able to add in a simple

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

on the bottom-most view in the XML layout to push it up. But that doesn't work! Instead, it aligns to the bottom of the navigation bar, which is not what I want - it should be aligned to the top of it.

I then figured I'd be able to do some sort of margin offset from the bottom, however an attribute similar to ?attr/actionBarSize does not seem to exist for the navigation bar. I would like to avoid picking arbitrary values (especially as these are different depending on the orientation and could conceivably change in the future)

In the theme, I'm aware you're able to add in -

```
<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
```

Which kind of accomplishes this (for the navigation bar at least), however then the image will be pushed below the action bar. It seems I'm able to get the desired outcome for either the navigation bar or the action bar but never both at the same time. It's almost as if Google doesn't even want people doing this, yet they've given this example on the Material website.

Are there any ways to get around these issues?

Comment: Add padding to the `android.R.id.content` to the size of the navigation bar. This will move the content up and keep the image in the status bar not pushed down below the actionbar.

Comment: Have you been able to reproduce this effect in the emulator?

Comment: Afraid not. Instead, I just kept the status bar a solid color.